# Android 5 Lollipop block Advertising video in a game

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ads

I have a "problem" with a game called `Geometry Dash Lite`, sometime meanwhile I play an advertisement shows and consume a lot of internet bandwidth...

The advertisement is a video of another game (here's a screenshot)

[image]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Here's the "stolen" bandwidth image

[image]
Click for full size

There is a way (without rooting) to block it? (leaving aside the possibility to complete disable the mobile internet connection)

Answer (score 1):

Without root, your best options would likely be:

- Disable your cellular data while playing (assuming the game does not require it)
- [Purchase the ad-free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.robtopx.geometryjump)